# This app is not Authorized to use FireBase Authentication.Please verify Correct package name and SHA 1 Certificate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error again and again. I have searched a lot about this error. I got the following solutions.

1:- Add SHA 1 key of android application from Android Studio in Firebase project settings.

2:-Verify the package name of the application used in the Firebase project.

3:-Resync project after connecting the android project to Firebase.

4:-Turn on Firebase phone Authentication from Firebase console ( i already turned on)

5:-I created a new project on firebase and connected my app to Firebase, also I verified SHA 1 key and Project name.

After all these solutions I got no result. The error still exists.

I will provide the complete source code of my project. Please I need help. Please help me. I will give a personal contact to keep in touch.

I will give complete information about this project. I am a student and I am unable to solve this problem for 2 weeks.

please any one helps me for the sake of God.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

After spending the whole Day figuring out what was the issue. I’ve found the culprit! It was in the App Signing for Google Play that we have opted-in.We need to register the SHA-1 from the App Signing itself. It can be found in the inside Google Play Console under Release Management > App Signing. It will have two types of certificate:
1.**Upload certificate**: this is the information of the certificate from the keystore that uploaded. This is needed to be the same with the keystore for app signing locally as the Google Play will verify the uploaded app to match with this signed certificate.

2.**App Signing certificate**: after uploaded the app, Google will replace the upload certificate with this certificate. This is a new certificate that will be used for published app in Play Store.

With those information, I just realize that we hadn’t registered the SHA-1 for the App Signing certificate which being used by published app. 
So, I added the SHA-1 (also the SHA-256, just in case needed) fingerprints in the Firebase > Project Setting for the app (Don’t forget to update the latest config file after added the fingerprints).

So After adding your your SHA Fingerprints your Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints will look like this:

[image: So After adding your your SHA Fingerprints your Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints will look like this:]

Now Save Changes then Go back to your App and test it again it will work now!.

Comment: I got this to work without having to do anything with the Google Play Console.  But your comment has helpful because I didn't go the Android properties and fill out the data that was needed in the Android Package Signing.  lol duh!  All the tutorials I have read failed to mention that you needed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try First

> Tools>Firebase>Authentication>Connect>Sync

And Remember in the [Update - June 12, 2018](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) you must have to add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

If It Is Not Work Then Visit [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview?pli=1) and Delete your Project and SHA-1 from here then retry Again. Hope It's Working.